# Subscript out of range when using date input macro

Tags: excel, vba

Admittedly bit of a rookie/novice here but have successfully modified a fair bit of code in the past. Running a macro that brings up a UI box to enter date and client booking fields, previous editions of the file worked without issue, however since porting macros etc into a 2016 excel file, I now get this error on even previously working copies. Have tested and previous files work fine on all other logins/computers other than my own.

Receiving Error 9, subscript out of range pointing to the following code, which reads off of a calendar generated on a hidden worksheet;

Code is ;

```
'~~> Ok Button
Private Sub CommandButton53_Click()
   BookedInDate = Me.TextBox1.Text

   Dim Day As String
   Dim Month As String
   Dim Year As String

   Day = Split(Me.TextBox1.Text, "/")(0)
    Month = Split(Me.TextBox1.Text, "/")(1)
     Year = Split(Me.TextBox1.Text, "/")(2)

   BookedDate = DateSerial(Year, Month, Day)

'   ActiveSheet.Range("BE" & cell.row).Value = Me.txtTimeIn.Text

   varTimeIn = Replace(Me.txtTimeIn.Text, ".", ":")



   'BookedDate = dateserial(me.TextBox1.
   'WSLoc2.Close


 '  WSLoc2.Delete


   Unload Me
   End Sub
```

Absolutely wracking my brain trying to figure out mainly why I am now receiving this error on previously functional workbooks, any advice would be greatly appreciated. Debug tool is pointing me at

```
Month = Split(Me.TextBox1.Text, "/")(1)
```

Code that the split function references:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
 Dim dat As Date
    dat = DateAdd("m", 1, DateSerial(Val(Format(CommandButton45.Caption, "YYYY")), Val(Format(CommandButton45.Caption, "MM")), 1))
'    GenerateCal Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yyyy")
    CommandButton45.Caption = Format(Now(), "mmm - yyyy")
    Me.TextBox1.Text = Format(Now(), "d/mm/yyyy")
```

Comment: Which line cause error?

Comment: Month = Split(Me.TextBox1.Text, "/")(1)

Is where the debug tool is pointing me, sorry

Comment: What's the value of `Me.TextBox1.Text` ?  If it doesn't contain at least one "/" this line will fail.

Comment: Value of the textbox is a button selected date, userform macro enters it as dd-mm-yyyy, will add the code for this to the original post. 

What has me most stumped is that the new and old versions of the files work perfectly on standard staff logins, only issue appears to be on our management accounts

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for [Format Function (Visual Basic for Applications)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications) states:

> **User-Defined Date/Time Formats (Format Function)** The following table
>   identifies characters you can use to create user-defined date/time
>   formats:
>
> ( / ) **Date separator**. In some locales, other characters
>   may be used to represent the date separator. The date separator
>   separates the day, month, and year when date values are formatted. The
>   actual character used as the date separator in formatted output is
>   determined by your system settings.

That means the `/` in format strings for dates is locale dependent. Example:

```
Dim s As String
s = Format(Now(), "d/mm/yyyy")
MsgBox s
```

in my German Excel results in `s` = `18.04.2018` today because in my German locale the dot `.` is the date separator.

If you always wants the slash being the separator between day month and year in your date strings, then do using:

```
Dim s As String
s = Format(Now(), "d\/mm\/yyyy")
MsgBox s
```

There the backslash masks the slash not having special meaning as "the date separator" .